# Can you add logs files to NUnit

Tags: nunit

I am fairly new to NUnit and I'm trying to see if NUnit support multiple logging, by that I mean that I want to capture the logs from an external device as well as the network traces. Since I don't want to pollute my result logs with all these logs, I would like to have them in different files so that I have something like this:

- Test results logs file
- Telnet logs file 1
- Telnet logs file 2
- Network trace file

Does Nunit support the addition of other logs or do I have to create my own logging system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, NUnit's result file is not a "log file." Generally, a log file is created incrementally as execution proceeds. The TestResult file is an XML representation of the entire test run and is only written at the end of the run.

NUnit does have a set of log files, called Internal Trace logs, which are produced by the  console runner when you use the --trace option. As their name suggests, they trace the internal workings of NUnit rather than your tests.

Any other logging you perform is entirely up to you and is not captured by NUnit at all.